# How do I add TimeSpan in C# inside Loop?

Tags: c#

Can anyone please tell me I need to add time with interval with in the for loop. This is my C# code.

```
var t1 = selectedTime.TimeOfDay;
t1 = 8.00 //assum time is 8.00           
for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)  {
    var duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    var t3 = duration;
}
```

My output should be:

```
8.00
8.15
8.30
8.45
9.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use the `DateTime.AddMinutes()` method:

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(t1.AddMinutes(15 * i).ToString("HH:mm")); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The gotcha in your original code is increment and persist the new value; in this snippet I updated the `t1` variable:

```
var selectedTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8);
var t1 = selectedTime.TimeOfDay;    //assume time is 8.00           
for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t1);
    t1 += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var t1 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    //t1 = 8.00 //assum time is 8.00   
    var duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15); 
    Console.WriteLine(t1); // print current time
    for (int i = 0; i <=4; i++)
    {        
        t1 += duration; // add timespan 4 times
        Console.WriteLine(t1);  
    }
```

You can add TimeSpan to the DateTime easily. You just need to make sure you are remembering the previous value or by increasing the time span (eg. 15 min, 30 min etc) in each loop cycle.

Comment: Print start from 8.15, how do I print all (8.00, 8.15..etc..)

Comment: first printing is before the loop - it should print 8:00. In case you don't want that line, you can remove it and switch lines in the loop, so first you are printing and then adding the timespan.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeSpan` is added using the `+ operator` with another `TimeSpan`, for example, I can implement this 15 seconds interval loop using `Linq` as the following:

```
TimeSpan initialTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 2);
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> spans = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
    .Select(x => x * 15)
    .Select(x => initialTimeSpan + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x));

foreach (TimeSpan span in spans)
{
    Console.WriteLine(span);
}
```

To add it to a `DateTime` use the `Add` method:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan initialTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 2);
date = date.Add(initialTimeSpan);
```

Or you can just add the period you wish without using `TimeSpan` by using the `AddSeconds`/`AddMinutes`/`AddHours`/`AddMilliseconds`/`AddTicks`/`AddYears`/`AddDays`/`AddMonths` methods:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan initialTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 2);
date = date.AddSeconds(5);
```

You can use everything in a loop like that:

```
DateTime initialTime = DateTime.Now;
for (DateTime loopTime = initialTime; loopTime < initialTime.AddMinutes(2); loopTime = loopTime.AddSeconds(15))
{
    Console.WriteLine(loopTime);
}
```

And you will get the following output:

```
26/09/2015 13:00:33
26/09/2015 13:00:48
26/09/2015 13:01:03
26/09/2015 13:01:18
26/09/2015 13:01:33
26/09/2015 13:01:48
26/09/2015 13:02:03
26/09/2015 13:02:18
```

To get the output in the format you wanted you can change the printing to the following:

```
Console.Write(loopTime.Minute + ".");
if (loopTime.Second < 10)
{
    Console.Write(0);
}
Console.WriteLine(loopTime.Second);
```

And you will get this output for the same hours shown above:

```
0.33
0.48
1.03
1.18
1.33
1.48
2.03
2.18
```

Comment: Thank you answer, what I need to (int i = 0; i <=NumberOfRecord; i++) because how can I added your code NumberOfRecord?

Comment: I've added an example for the loop you want which makes the loop with `i` redundant.